# Mysql advanced joins in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

[image: tables to join]

i have three tables: posts,comments and replies

- Replies tables is same as post table but its a reply to the post
- Posts table have comments
- Replies table also have comments
- Comment table is to store comments of replies table and posts tables
- I wish to get all posts which have comments even though reply of a post have comment then also that post is included, and resultant posts should be unique...

This is what i have tried::

```
$RC = DB::table('comments')
    ->join('replies','comments.reply_id','=','replies.id')
    ->where('comments.handle',$request->handle)
    ->where('replies.handle','!=',$request->handle)
    ->groupBy('replies.post_id')
    ->get(['replies.post_id']);

$PC = DB::table('comments')
    ->join('posts', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->where('comments.handle',$request->handle)
    ->where('posts.handle','!=',$request->handle)
    ->groupBy('comments.post_id')
    ->get(['comments.post_id']);
```

Comment: What have you implemented for this?

Comment: Read the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships and show us what you have done regarding it

Comment: @ShaunakShukla i have posted what i have tried

Comment: Why did you create two queries? I think you want to get all posts with their respective replies and comments to post and replies.

Comment: I don't know how to combine both and get sufficient result that's why i have posted my doubt here @ShaunakShukla

Comment: one more question... what is 'handle' in 'replies.handle','comments.handle','posts.handle'?

Comment: user's handle who is requesting all posts he commented

Comment: There should be a column for that in your table structure image. Can you be more specific about this line of code: `where('replies.handle','!=',$request->handle)`  and `where('posts.handle','!=',$request->handle)`? because this indicates that you only need comments of that user no other details you need.

Comment: This means i don't need posts of the requesting  user which are posted and commented by himself

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts JOIN replies ON posts.id = replies.post_id JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id OR replies.id = comments.reply_id WHERE posts.handle != $request->handle` This query may be helpful to you!

Comment: That query is giving only posts which have comments for their replies

Comment: @ShaunakShukla see above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'm using this code to get desired results

```
$res = DB::select("SELECT posts.* FROM posts JOIN replies ON posts.id = replies.post_id 
                    JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id OR replies.id = comments.reply_id 
                    WHERE comments.handle = $request->handle AND posts.handle != $request->handle 
                    GROUP BY posts.id");

$res1 = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('comments',function ($join){
        $join->on('posts.id','=','comments.post_id')
            ->where('comments.handle','=',$request->handle)
            ->Where('posts.handle','<>',$request->handle);
    })
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->get(['posts.*']);
$results = array_merge($res,$res1);
$results= collect($results);
$results = $results->unique();
```